# t-sql, replace Null with last value - contains Unions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following query:

```
declare @s1_data int;
declare @s2_data int;
declare @s3_data int;
declare @s4_data int;
declare @s5_data int;
declare @s6_data int;

select  aa.t_stamp, 
        aa.Stat as S1_Stat, 
        @s2_data as S2_Stat, 
        @s3_data as S3_Stat, 
        @s4_data as S4_Stat, 
        @s5_data as S5_Stat, 
        @s6_data as S6_Stat 
from Line4283_1_rtStat aa 
where t_stamp between '{Root Container.Date Range.startDate}' 
                  and '{Root Container.Date Range.endDate}'
Union
select ab.t_stamp, @s1_data, ab.Stat ,@s3_data, @s4_data, @s5_data, @s6_data 
from Line4283_2_rtStat ab
where t_stamp between '{Root Container.Date Range.startDate}' 
                  and '{Root Container.Date Range.endDate}'
Union
select ac.t_stamp, @s1_data, @s2_data, ac.Stat, @s4_data, @s5_data, @s6_data 
from Line4283_3_rtStat ac
where t_stamp between '{Root Container.Date Range.startDate}'  
                  and '{Root Container.Date Range.endDate}'
Union
select ad.t_stamp, @s1_data, @s2_data, @s3_data, ad.Stat, @s5_data, @s6_data 
from Line4283_4_rtStat ad
where t_stamp between '{Root Container.Date Range.startDate}'  
                  and '{Root Container.Date Range.endDate}'
Union
select ae.t_stamp, @s1_data, @s2_data, @s3_data ,@s4_data, ae.Stat, @s6_data 
from Line4283_5_rtStat ae
where t_stamp between '{Root Container.Date Range.startDate}'  
                  and '{Root Container.Date Range.endDate}'
Union
select af.t_stamp, @s1_data, @s2_data, @s3_data ,@s4_data ,@s5_data, af.Stat 
from Line4283_6_rtStat af
where t_stamp between '{Root Container.Date Range.startDate}'  
                  and '{Root Container.Date Range.endDate}'
union
select '{Root Container.Date Range.endDate}', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

The `{Root Container.Date Range.startDate}` and `{Root Container.Date Range.endDate}` are variables that are populated at runtime.

This query works and returns something like this except that this is the result from just reading the first two rows of data:

```
2018-03-29 11:00:00.000     2       NULL
2018-03-29 12:00:00.000     3       NULL
2018-03-29 13:00:00.000     4       NULL
2018-04-09 15:57:57.270     2       NULL
2018-04-09 16:01:10.193     NULL    1
2018-04-09 16:01:46.430     NULL    7
2018-04-09 16:02:09.547     NULL    1
2018-04-09 16:04:23.710     NULL    3
2018-04-09 16:04:40.850     NULL    1
2018-04-09 16:04:49.907     NULL    3
2018-04-09 16:04:52.920     NULL    1
etc'
```

To make this work I would like to replace the NULL values with the last value that occurred in that same column. I am not sure how to do this with all these unions that are needed to get the data into a workable format.

The query needs to return data the way it is currently structured to allow the tool that I am importing the data into to display the data correctly.

Exact SQL Server Version: 13.0.4210.6

I ended up doing to following. Below is a copy of the procedure I wrote:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[statusFill] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @start datetime,
 @end datetime
AS
BEGIN

declare @insertDate datetime;
declare @insertDateSpan datetime;
declare @s1_stat int;
declare @s1_hold int;
declare @s2_stat int;
declare @s2_hold int;
declare @s3_stat int;
declare @s3_hold int;
declare @s4_stat int;
declare @s4_hold int;
declare @s5_stat int;
declare @s5_hold int;
declare @s6_stat int;
declare @s6_hold int;

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET @insertDate = @start;
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='status' AND xtype='U')
drop table #status

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='status' AND xtype='U')
create table #status
( 
t_stamp datetime,
S1_Stat int,
S2_Stat int,
S3_Stat int,
S4_Stat int,
S5_Stat int,
S6_Stat int
)

WHILE @insertDate < @end
BEGIN
select @insertDateSpan = DATEADD(second,5,@insertDate)
if @insertDate = @start
    select @s1_stat = isnull((select top (1) stat from Line4283_1_rtStat     where t_stamp between @insertDate and @insertDateSpan order by t_stamp asc),
    (select top (1) stat from Line4283_1_rtStat where t_stamp <     @insertDate order by t_stamp asc))  
else
    select @s1_stat = isnull((select top (1) stat from Line4283_1_rtStat where t_stamp between @insertDate and @insertDateSpan order by t_stamp asc),@s1_hold)

if @s1_stat is not null
    select @s1_hold = @s1_stat;

-- station #2
if @insertDate = @start
    select @s2_stat = isnull((select top (1) stat from Line4283_2_rtStat     where t_stamp between @insertDate and @insertDateSpan order by t_stamp asc),
    (select top (1) stat from Line4283_2_rtStat where t_stamp <     @insertDate order by t_stamp asc))  
else
    select @s2_stat = isnull((select top (1) stat from Line4283_2_rtStat where t_stamp between @insertDate and @insertDateSpan order by t_stamp asc),@s2_hold)

if @s2_stat is not null
    select @s2_hold = @s2_stat;

-- station #3
if @insertDate = @start
    select @s3_stat = isnull((select top (1) stat from Line4283_3_rtStat     where t_stamp between @insertDate and @insertDateSpan order by t_stamp asc),
    (select top (1) stat from Line4283_3_rtStat where t_stamp <     @insertDate order by t_stamp asc))  
else
    select @s3_stat = isnull((select top (1) stat from Line4283_3_rtStat where t_stamp between @insertDate and @insertDateSpan order by t_stamp asc),@s3_hold)

if  @s3_stat is not null
    select @s3_hold = @s3_stat;

    -- station #4
if @insertDate = @start
    select @s4_stat = isnull((select top (1) stat from Line4283_4_rtStat where t_stamp between @insertDate and @insertDateSpan order by t_stamp asc),
    (select top (1) stat from Line4283_2_rtStat where t_stamp < @insertDate order by t_stamp asc))  
else
    select @s4_stat = isnull((select top (1) stat from Line4283_4_rtStat where t_stamp between @insertDate and @insertDateSpan order by t_stamp asc),@s4_hold)

if @s4_stat is not null
    select @s4_hold = @s4_stat;
-- station #5
if @insertDate = @start
    select @s5_stat = isnull((select top (1) stat from Line4283_5_rtStat     where t_stamp between @insertDate and @insertDateSpan order by t_stamp asc),
    (select top (1) stat from Line4283_5_rtStat where t_stamp <     @insertDate order by t_stamp asc))  
else
    select @s5_stat = isnull((select top (1) stat from Line4283_5_rtStat where t_stamp between @insertDate and @insertDateSpan order by t_stamp asc),@s5_hold)

if @s5_stat is not null
    select @s5_hold = @s5_stat;

-- station #6
if @insertDate = @start
    select @s6_stat = isnull((select top (1) stat from Line4283_6_rtStat     where t_stamp between @insertDate and @insertDateSpan order by t_stamp asc),
    (select top (1) stat from Line4283_6_rtStat where t_stamp <     @insertDate order by t_stamp asc))  
else
    select @s6_stat = isnull((select top (1) stat from Line4283_6_rtStat where t_stamp between @insertDate and @insertDateSpan order by t_stamp asc),@s6_hold)

if @s6_stat is not null
    select @s6_hold = @s6_stat;






insert into #status (t_stamp,S1_Stat,S2_Stat,S3_Stat,S4_Stat,S5_Stat,S6_Stat)
select @insertDate,@s1_stat,@s2_stat,@s3_stat,@s4_stat,@s5_stat,@s6_stat
select @insertDate =DATEADD(second,5,@insertDate)
END;


select t_stamp,S1_Stat,S2_Stat,S3_Stat,S4_Stat,S5_Stat,S6_Stat  from #status
drop table #status
END
```

This was a little different but it actually runs in under a second for typical executions. This allows me to create 5 second windows and either fill them with data or stick the last known value in.

Comment: Your query doesn't have an `order by` clause so you don't *really* have a *last value*. Without an `order by` specified, rows are returned in an arbitrary order.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. I didnt think about it because it is returning in the correct order. Good catch...so....if I order it by the timestamp column do you have a thought for how to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Yes, basically you need subqueries for that. I hope I'll have the time to write a proper answer tomorow.

Comment: Thanks Zohar...you got me on the right track...I think. Let me know what you think of my solution above.